# Reference request: Bipartite symmetric graphs are hamiltonian

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, hamiltonian-graphs

Does anyone know whether bipartite symmetric graphs are hamiltonian?
I'm not sure whether anyone have proved it before, but a nonhamiltonian symmetric bipartite graph would lead to a counterexample to the Lovasz conjecture. I would appreciate any references or ideas.

Comment: What do you mean by symmetric?

Comment: A symmetric graph is a graph that is both edge- and vertex-transitive.

Comment: But then it cannot be bipartite.

Comment: Why can't it be bipartite? The cube is both symmetric and bipartite.

Comment: You are right, sorry.

Comment: As far as I know, nothing substantive about the question of whether vertex-transitive graphs have Hamilton cycles (other than the handful of known non Hamiltonian examples) has recently been proved. There has been some progress  on gradually increasing the number of families of transitive graphs known to be Hamiltonian, but far short of extending to either bipartite or symmetric (or both) graphs.

Comment: So are there any examples where some kind of graph symmetry implies hamiltonicity?

Comment: Not quite, but things like Cayley graphs of certain groups, or transitive graphs of certain orders (products of few primes). Look up the work of Dave Witte (aka Dave Morris) and Joy Morris.

Comment: This may or may not be a triviality but I assume you mean Hamiltonian cycle in each **connected component** or that the graph is **connected**. i.e., not a vertex-disjoint collection of cycles all of the same size.

Comment: I believe this is an open question. A decade-old yet still helpful related source is 'Annelies Heus: *A study of necessary and sufficient conditions for vertex transitive graphs to be Hamiltonian*. University of Amsterdam 2008'. The question is not answered there, needless to say.